# Jump into the next line in readlines inside for loop

Tags: python, readlines

I am writing a code to extract something useful from a very big `Source.txt` file.
A sample of my source test file is as below:

```
Test case AAA
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : 1
    Some unique param : 2
    Some unique param :     3
    Some unique param : 4
*A line of rubbish*
*Another line of rubbish*
*Yet another line of rubbish*
*More and more rubbish*
Test AAA PASS
Test case BBB
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : A
    Some unique param : B
    Some unique param :     C
    Some unique param : D
*A line of rubbish*
*Another line of rubbish*
*Yet another line of rubbish*
*More and more rubbish*
Test BBB PASS
```

Now I am writing a code to extract only the `Test case` and `Current Parameters`:

```
processed = []

def main():
    source_file = open("Source.txt","r") #Open the raw trace file in read mode
    if source_file.mode == "r":
        contents = source_file.readlines()   #Read the contents of the file
        processed_contents = _process_content(contents)
        output_file = open("Output.txt","w")
        output_file.writelines(processed_contents)
        pass

def _process_content(contents):
    for raw_lines in contents:
        if "Test case" in raw_lines:
            processed.append(raw_lines)
        elif "Current Parameters" in raw_lines:
            processed.append(raw_lines)
            #I am stuck here
        elif "PASS" in raw_lines or "FAIL" in raw_lines:
            processed.append(raw_lines)
            processed.append("\n")
    return processed

#def _process_parameters():


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After the line `Current Parameters`, I wanted to grab each of the `Some unique param` which will not be the same always and append to `processed` list so that it will be also noted in my Output.txt

My desired output is:

```
Test case AAA
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : 1
    Some unique param : 2
    Some unique param :     3
    Some unique param : 4
    Test AAA PASS
Test case BBB
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : A
    Some unique param : B
    Some unique param :     C
    Some unique param : D
    Test BBB PASS
```

If you see, I wanted to remove all the rubbish lines. Note that there are a lot of rubbish in my `Source.txt`. I am not sure how to go to the next `raw_lines` from there. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Adam.Er8, it is good. But I don't know how to continue to the line Param 1

Comment: why doesn't `elif "Param" in raw_lines`  work? does it also capture some of the rubbish?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention, the Param in raw_lines will always not always contain the word Param. Will edit the question now

Comment: OK, are these the only indented lines after `Current Parameters:`? because what we can do is mark a flag every time we encounter `Current Parameters:`, then also add all lines that are indented, and when we find one that isn't, take the flag down and go back to normal mode

Comment: Just edited the question, my params will be unique and not with the same name. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for raw_lines in infile:
        if "Test case" in raw_lines:
            result.append(raw_lines)
        if "Current Parameters" in raw_lines:
            result.append(raw_lines)
            raw_lines = next(infile)                        #next() to move to next line. 
            while True:
                m = re.search(r"(?P<params>\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*)", raw_lines)    
                if not m:
                    break
                result.append(m.group("params"))
                raw_lines = next(infile)
        if "PASS" in raw_lines or "FAIL" in raw_lines:
            result.append(raw_lines)
            result.append("\n")
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['Test case AAA\n',
 'Current Parameters:\n',
 ' param : 1\n',
 ' param : 2\n',
 ' param :     3\n',
 ' param : 4\n',
 'Test AAA PASS\n',
 '\n',
 'Test case BBB\n',
 'Current Parameters:\n',
 ' param : A\n',
 ' param : B\n',
 ' param :     C\n',
 ' param : D\n',
 'Test BBB PASS',
 '\n']
```

Comment: this seems to be the right solution. I will try and update you

Comment: This is working as expected with slight edit, thank a lot man

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure if this will work, because I don't know anything about the format of the rubbish lines, but I think you can just check to see if the line contains `"Param"`, just like you're doing for the other lines:

```
def _process_content(contents):
    for raw_line in contents:
        if "Test case" in raw_line:
            processed.append(raw_line)
        elif "Current Parameters" in raw_line:
            processed.append(raw_line)
        elif "Param" in raw_line:
            processed.append(raw_line)
        elif "PASS" in raw_line or "FAIL" in raw_lines:
            processed.append(raw_line)
            processed.append("\n")
    return processed
```

Comment: If the param lines don't always contain "Param", and instead, always start with some whitespace, you can do `elif raw_line.startswith("    ")`

Comment: I just edited my question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex back reference (e.g. `\2`) to split the test cases ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rMwXEj/3)):

```
import re

data = '''Test case AAA
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : 1
    Some unique param : 2
    Some unique param :     3
    Some unique param : 4
*A line of rubbish*
*Another line of rubbish*
*Yet another line of rubbish*
*More and more rubbish*
Test AAA PASS
Test case BBB
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : A
    Some unique param : B
    Some unique param :     C
    Some unique param : D
*A line of rubbish*
*Another line of rubbish*
*Yet another line of rubbish*
*More and more rubbish*
Test BBB PASS'''

for g in re.findall(r'(^Test case ([A-Za-z]+)\s+Current Parameters:(?:[^:]+:.*?$)*)+.*?(Test \2 (PASS|FAIL))', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M):
    print(g[0])
    print(g[2])
```

Prints:

```
Test case AAA
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : 1
    Some unique param : 2
    Some unique param :     3
    Some unique param : 4
Test AAA PASS
Test case BBB
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : A
    Some unique param : B
    Some unique param :     C
    Some unique param : D
Test BBB PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.startswith()` to filter out the lines you want, then rewrite these lines to the file again. I would also split the line on `":"`, and check idd the length is 2 to find paramters. It would also be safe to convert the lines to all lowercase as well, so you can do caseless matching, so it doesn't think `"Test"` is not the same is `"test"`.

**Demo:**

```
lines = []
with open("source.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lowercase = line.lower()
        if (
            lowercase.startswith("test")
            or lowercase.startswith("current parameters:")
            or len(lowercase.split(":")) == 2
        ):
            lines.append(line)

with open("source.txt", mode="w") as o:
    for line in lines:
        o.write(line)
```

**source.txt:**

```
Test case AAA
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : 1
    Some unique param : 2
    Some unique param :     3
    Some unique param : 4
Test AAA PASS
Test case BBB
Current Parameters:
    Some unique param : A
    Some unique param : B
    Some unique param :     C
    Some unique param : D
Test BBB PASS
```